# Email Address Verification

Tags: c#, validation, windows-phone-8, email-validation

So what I am trying to do is to verify an Email Address that the user will input himself.

Microsoft developer network offer a sample code of how to verify email address in the following link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Anyway I just copied the code and tried to use it. However I keep getting this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'IdnMapping' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I could not find any similar issue online and I can't think of what would cause this error.

Of course, what would first come to our mind when we see such an error is that we forgot to include something.

However I included whatever is needed as in the page above and as I will be showing in my code. So I really can't even understand the nature of the problem itself to start searching for a possible solution.

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
    {
        bool invalid = false;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strIn))
            return false;

        // Use IdnMapping class to convert Unicode domain names. 
        try
        {
            strIn = Regex.Replace(strIn, @"(@)(.+)$", this.DomainMapper,
                                  RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (invalid)
            return false;

        // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format. 
        try
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(strIn,
                  @"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
                  @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,24}))$",
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string DomainMapper(Match match)
    {
        // IdnMapping class with default property values.
        IdnMapping idn = new IdnMapping();

        string domainName = match.Groups[2].Value;
        try
        {
            domainName = idn.GetAscii(domainName);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            invalid = true;
        }
        return match.Groups[1].Value + domainName;
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue or at least understanding the nature of the issue.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like the IdnMapping class is there for some additional testing on the domain name in the email address. Honestly, the regex part you have is probably enough.

Comment: It says in a comment 3 lines above where it is used: it converts Unicode domain names. It may come in handy with the new TLDs coming out, but for most of the cases, it's hardly needed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the class doesn't exist on .NET for Windows Phone.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.idnmapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says it only exists on .NET Framework 2.0+ and .NET Framework Client Profile 3.5 SP1+.

Comment: So are you aware of any possible alternatives for windows 8 phone ?

Comment: Sadly, I am not. I have not done much Windows Phone 8 development myself. However, I think you can safely drop the Regex.Replace line which uses the method which needs the missing class. Eventually, you can use it on your server to do this replacement (and in case of failure, report to the client). (assuming you have/use a server)

Answer (score 1):

Try this RFC822-compliant method:

```
    var text = @"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
\t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\0
31]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\
](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+
(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:
(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\
r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)
*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+
|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r
\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031
]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?
:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?
:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?
:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?
[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|
\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>
@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""
(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\
"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?
:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[
\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-
\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;
:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([
^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\""
.\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\
]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\
[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\
r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]
|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \0
00-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\
.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,
;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?
:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".
\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[
^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]
]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:,\s*(
?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\
"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[
\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?
:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|
\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:
[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\
]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""
()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>
@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,
;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\
"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".
\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[
""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|""(?:[^\""\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*""(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
+|\Z|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\
.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\[""()<>@,;:\\"".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)?;\s*)".Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Then you can do this:

```
    var emailRegex = new Regex(text);

    var isValid = emailRegex.IsMatch("foo@bar.com");
```

Seriously this is correct.

Comment: @Vercas - I'm pretty darn sure it isn't.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your source? I'm dieing to know its origin.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MailAddress class, here is a nice a piece of code.
The reason is that someone else has already done the Regex for you.

```
    public bool IsValid(string emailaddress)
    {
        try
        {
            MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Windows Phone Silverlight. `MailAddress` class doesn't exist.

Answer (score -2):

Ok I just found this one right now, it seems to be working for me and I just wanted to share it.

```
private bool IsValidEmail(string emailAddress)
{
        // Return true if emailAddress is in valid e-mail format.
        return Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, @"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with gmail accounts that contain +, doesn't support underscores, doesn't support any new TDL